# Establishing TCP socket connection between PHP client and C server on Ubuntu

Tags: php, c, linux, sockets

I am writing a simple PHP client and C server programs on Ubuntu 16.04. On client side I have made a simple graphical user interface in HTML, in which there is only one drop down box, and a submit button. When I click on the button, PHP client code is executed (though Apache server), but the client does not connect to the server, which is initially launched in terminal.

I want to pass the value of drop down box to the C server, whatever user selects from drop down. Please help me to figure out what's wrong with my code.

**Server.c**

```
//All Libraries are present including pthread

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

//the thread function

void *connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

  int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;

  struct sockaddr_in server , client;

  socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

  if (socket_desc == -1)
  {

    printf("Could not create socket");

  }

  puts("Socket created");

  server.sin_family = AF_INET;

  server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );
  //Bind
  if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
  {


    perror("bind failed. Error");
    return 1;
  }
  puts("bind done");

  listen(socket_desc , 3);

  c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

  int threadID;

  //Accept and incoming connection

  puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

  c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

  while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )

  {

    puts("Connection accepted");

    pthread_t sniffer_thread;

    new_sock = malloc(1);

    *new_sock = client_sock;

    threadID=pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock);

    if( threadID < 0)

    {

      perror("could not create thread");

      return 1;

    }

    puts("Handler assigned");

  }



  if (client_sock < 0)

  {

    perror("accept failed");

    return 1;

  }

  return 0;

}

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)

{

  int read_size;

  char *serverErrorMsg="Invalid Details!";

  char client_message[2000],client_poll[2000];

  int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;


  //Receive a message from client

  if( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )

  {
    puts("Server Received: ");

    puts(client_message);

  }

  else

  {

    write(sock , serverErrorMsg , strlen(serverErrorMsg));

  }

  free(socket_desc);    

  return 0;

}
```

**Client.php**

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host    = "127.0.0.1";

$port    = 8888;

// create socket

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

// connect to server

$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  

// sending test type to server

$selectedType = $_POST['testType']; //html drop down with name='testType'

socket_write($socket, $selectedType, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");

socket_close($socket);

?>
```

Comment: Show us the output in terminal, how you launch the client/server, and what do you expect from both programs.

Answer (score 0):

The code is full of bugs.

### Server.c

**Checking return values**

If `socket()` fails, you only print a message to the standard output. The program continues to run with invalid descriptor:

```
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
if (socket_desc == -1) {
  printf("Could not create socket");
}
```

**Standard input/output**

You should print errors to the standard error descriptor, then `abort()`, or exit with a non-zero exit code, e.g.:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (socket_desc == -1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  exit(1);
}
```

**`-Wall`**

Obviously, you haven't compiled the code with warnings on:

```
a.c:xxx:yy warning: unused variable ‘client_poll’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Always compile with `-Wall`.

**`sizeof`**

There is no need in storing the result of `sizeof` in memory, as `sizeof` is a compile-time operator:

```
/* Don't do this. Use a macro, if you want to shorten sizeof expression */
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)
```

**Closing the socket**

The socket descriptor should be closed when a session has been completed:

```
close(socket_desc);
```

Otherwise, use `SOCK_CLOEXEC` flag (`socket()`'s `type` argument).

**Accessing the sockets from thread handler**

You allocate only single byte for the file descriptor for the accepted socket:

```
new_sock = malloc(1);
```

You can simply [cast integer to void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487380/how-to-cast-an-integer-to-void-pointer):

```
#include <stdint.h>

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
  int sock = (intptr_t) socket_desc;
  /* ... */
}

threadID = pthread_create(&sniffer_thread, NULL,
  connection_handler, (void *)(intptr_t) new_sock);
```

Even if you want to use `malloc` for the hell of it, use the `sizeof` operator:

```
/* Allocates memory for an integer */
new_sock = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

**Regarding `pthread_create()`**

The code apparently "thinks" that `pthread_create()` function returns a thread ID. It doesn't. The return value is zero on success, otherwise it is an error code.

From the moment you spawn a thread, you are responsible for its life cycle until it terminates. Particularly, you should wait for the child threads to terminate using `pthread_join()` function. The latter accepts a `pthread_t`, which is initialized by `pthread_create()`. So you need to store `pthread_t` buffers somewhere. E.g.:

```
int rc, i = 0;
const int MAX_THREADS = 10;
pthread_t *threads = calloc(sizeof(pthread_t), MAX_THREADS);
struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
socklen_t addr_size;

puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
addr_size = sizeof their_addr;
while ((client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size)) > 0) {
  puts("Connection accepted");

  if (i >= MAX_THREADS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Max threads limit exceeded: %d, closing client socket\n", i);
    close(client_sock);
    break;
  }

  rc = pthread_create(&threads[i++], NULL,
      connection_handler, (void *)(intptr_t) client_sock);
  if (rc) {
    perror("could not create thread");
    break;
  }
}

if (threads) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
    if (threads[i])
      pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }
  free(threads);
}
```

**Signal handlers**

The program accepts connection until thread limit exceeds, or the user presses <kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd>, or terminates the process in other way. You should attach the signal handlers, and implement interthread communication to properly stop `accept`ing connections etc. As this goes beyond the scope of the question, I'll leave it for self-study.

Finally, don't use C++ comments in C.

### Client.php

You are passing length of undefined variable `$message` to `socket_write`:

```
socket_write($socket, $selectedType, strlen($message));
```

Since the variable is undefined, the length is evaluated to zero, which means that you send nothing to the server. Here is a fixed version, for completeness:

```
socket_write($socket, $selectedType, strlen($selectedType));
```

### Testing

After fixing the above, the programs respond to the user input:

*Terminal 1*

```
$ ./server
Socket created
bind done
Waiting for incoming connections...
Connection accepted
Server Received: 
test
```

*Terminal 2*

I've changed `$selectedType` in `Client.php` for testing in CLI:

```
$selectedType = isset($_POST['testType']) ? $_POST['testType'] : 'test';
```

```
$ php Client.php
```